# I can't get my RegEx expression to work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm using the following on my site:

`$('body').html($('body').html().replace(>> ?(\d+)/g, '<b>$&</b>'));`

(I'm using jQuery)

The Regular Expression I'm using is `>> ?(\d+)/g`.  The Bold below shows what it *should* be replacing:

> This passage of text **>> 124949200** contains two slightly **>>20993910** different regular expressions.

Now, I've used this tool here:  http://regexpal.com/  and my RegEx works fine.  When I actually implement it, however, it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: where's the opening slash (`/`)?

Comment: @Joseph I'll admit, today is my first work with RegEx.  Thanks for pointing that out though, I'll make sure I go and add that now.  +1 for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery's `html()` function appears to be outputting the `>>` as encoded characters: `&gt;&gt;`. Simply change your regular expression to this:

```
$('body').html($('body').html().replace(/&gt;&gt; ?(\d+)/g, '<b>$&</b>'));
```

Comment: Wow, nice catch.  I figured it must be something obscure like that! I'll Have to make sure I keep that in mind for next time...

Comment: @DadeLamkins - You and me both! I only noticed it because it showed up like that in an alert box while I was playing with your regex. In the HTML it obviously just shows up as `>>`.